# How to view recently submitted bugs in Debian bugtracker

Tags: debian, bugs

I run Debian testing and occasionally notice hiccups in my system. I'd like to be able to see if someone has reported a related bug, but don't always know what package names to look for. Or, before running a dist-upgrade I might just want to see if there has been a spike in bug reports in the last few days just to see if something major has recently broken.

Is there some way to just have the Debian Bug Report website spit back a list of bugs, sorted by submission date? Almost all the documentation for [the Debian bugracker](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/) is about how to submit a bug report. Just submitting a bug report request that's blank other than ordered by age doesn't work, nor does a report request that's blank except for "recent bugs." Using * for the package name doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's indeed poorly documented. You can display the latest 100 entries using this link:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?newest=100

You can further narrow your search by selecting the desired distribution, ex.
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?newest=100;dist=stable[2](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?newest=100;dist=stable)

This will take you to a form where you can enter search crteria
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?newest=;dist=stable

Answer (score 0):

From the Bug Page you linked:
You can search bug reports using our [HyperEstraier based search engine](http://bugs-search.debian.org/cgi-bin/search.cgi).

Add Attribute:
Date
Submission Date etc.

Comment: That could use a little more documentation. I tried for least 25 by submission date. Seems it wants more.

Comment: I got 500 trying to use it.

Comment: @Braiam What actual criteria are you entering for date/submission date? No matter what I try putting in as the date/submission date criteria, hitting "search" just seems to refresh the page. EDIT: Even the search "package" "includes (string)" "kde" returns nothing for me, so maybe I just don't understand how to use the search boxes?

Comment: When I tried it, I set Date to String, Exact Match, put in todays Date and searched for gnome  I received a 500 - Internal Server Error, same as Braiam.  As Such, I think their CGI script needs more documentation (Faheem), and a refresh